# Meaning of 両方じゃだめ

Tags: translation

I've recently discovered some Duolingo stickers on my phone, and there is one I can't translate properly. This sticker has the text 両方じゃだめ with a shrugging Duo-owl under it.

I think it means something along the lines of "I can't decide". Could anyone explain what it really means, and possibly break up the sentence?

The sticker:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 両方じゃだめ？

We usually say it to mean...

> "Can't I have them both?" "Why not both?"

---

It breaks down to...

両方 -- "both"
じゃ < contraction of では (で+は)
だめ -- "no good"

So it's *literally* like "is it no good if both?"

Comment: I'm guessing it's a reference to the "Why not both?" taco girl meme.

Comment: @Leebo あらっ、そおなんですか。ありがとうございます＾＾